# How can I derive a list of records that are not common across two dataframes?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, duplicates, vlookup, isin

I have two dataframes relating to securities - same structures / datatypes, just different sizes.

```
df1:

     security_ID     market_cap
0    ajax123         100000
1    apple456        10000
2    amazon513       20000
3    firefly312      200000


df2:
    
         security_ID     market_cap
    0    ajax123         100000
    1    apple456        10000
    2    amazon513       20000
    3    google566       200000
```

I want to do a vlookup style check, to identify the security IDs that are in df1 but not in df2, and vice-versa. I would then like to drop these security IDs so that I have two equalised dataframes for further analysis.

I have tried to use the following approach to get this, but to no avail:

```
df1['sec_id_check'] = df1['security_ID'].isin(df2['security_ID'])
```

This should have ideally populated the `df1['sec_id_check']` with 'True' and 'False', but all I get is 'True' across all 12,498 entries. I repeated exactly the same approach in reverse for `df2`, by creating the `df['sec_id_check']` column, and again, I got only 'True' across all 12,510 records

I know for a fact that there are securities that don't exist across both datasets - firefly123 in df1 doesn't exist in df2, and google566 is in df2 but not in df1 - I would have expected these to have been flagged as 'False' in my test.

Look forward to your responses - thanks very much in advance!

Comment: When it is return all True mean all ID in df1 contain in df2

Comment: correct - but I know that all IDs in df1 do not exist in df2, so clearly I have done something wrong! Thank you for your comment though, I have edited my query to make it more useful...

Comment: Run your sample with your code , it do flag as False ~

Comment: Ah ok - how can I return just the false entries for me to take a look?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code work for

```
m = df1['security_ID'].isin(df2['security_ID'])
print(df1[m])
```

Comment: this returns the full set, but from a visual check I see that only 12,339 rows have returned this time - all of them presumably marked 'True'. The df1 dataset actually consists of 12,498 rows - so the remainder must be the ones I'm after.

Is there an 'opposite' of isin?

Comment: @SQLGIT_GeekInTraining `m = ~df1['security_ID'].isin(df2['security_ID'])` adding `~` before it :-)

Comment: fantastic - cheers. I can see the 159 securities that don't exist in the other dataframe. Now the only question is - how can I remove them from df1 ?

Comment: @SQLGIT_GeekInTraining `df1 = df1[df1['security_ID'].isin(df2['security_ID'])]`

Comment: unfortunately I get a key error :( ? it literally says key error: 'security_id'

Comment: @SQLGIT_GeekInTraining security_id or security_ID ?

Comment: Fixed :) I think somewhere the dataframe was manipulated so I reran the notebook and it worked perfectly :) thanks so much....

Answer (score 2):

Let's use [`pd.DataFrame.compare`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.compare.html?highlight=compare#pandas.DataFrame.compare) new in version 1.1.0.

```
df1.compare(df2)
```

Output:

```
 security_ID           
         self      other
3  firefly312  google566
```

Comment: That's cool - unfortunately a) I get an error saying that the dataframe object has no attribute 'compare' and b) the indexation here doesn't matter.. all I'm after is a list of securities that exist in one and not the other.

Comment: is the compare will match the index as well  ?

Comment: Nope, the dataframes must have matching indexing.  But you can compare with the dataframe columns or rows using axis=1 or axis=0.

Comment: Well, I guess you could do axis=0 and only do the rows.  It is using pd.Series.compare underneath.

Comment: @SQLGIT_GeekInTraining This is a new feature in pandas 1.1.0.  You may need to upgrade to get this functionality.

Comment: ok thanks Scott - are you aware of another approach?

Comment: @SQLGIT_GeekInTraining BEN_YO has the correct solution I think.